# ¿Cómo podría extraer una parte de un audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**¿Cómo podría extraer una parte de un audio?**

Para que me entiendan un poco; yo necesito por ejemplo, escuchar el audio desde el segundo 5 hasta el segundo 10. Yo traigo el audio desde un fileserver y el código que usé para reproducir el audio fue el siguiente:

```
function reproducirAudio(path, file) {     
     var files = path + file;     
    $("#player2").attr("src", files).trigger("play"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola sí estas usando un elemento de audio común podrías usar `currentTime`

`audio.currentTime = 5;`

y para detenerlo luego de 10 segundos usas un `setTimeout`, algo como esto:

```
setTimeout(function(){audio.pause();},10000);
```

tu código quedaría así:

```
function reproducirAudio(path, file) {     
     var files = path + file;     
    $("#player2").attr("src", files):
    $("#player2").currentTime = 5;
    $("#player2").trigger("play");
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#player2").pause();},10000);

}
```

te sugiero crear una variable para usar el objeto `$("#player2")` por ejemplo:

```
var audio = $("#player2");
audio.currentTime=5;
....
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda Jhoubert Rincon. Me sirvió de un montón.